# Build failed in Flutter app due to video_compress package

Tags: android, flutter, dart, video-compression, pub.dev

I have been working an a flutter project that requires to upload video and thumbnail.
I used flutter video_compress package to compress the video and get a thumbnail.
After Adding video_compress package to `pubspec.yaml` file i found this error.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.otaliastudios:transcoder:0.9.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/otaliastudios/transcoder/0.9.1/transcoder-0.9.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/otaliastudios/transcoder/0.9.1/transcoder-0.9.1.pom
       - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/otaliastudios/transcoder/0.9.1/transcoder-0.9.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :video_compress

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried  `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` command but build results same error.

My code in video Controller is.

```
  _compressVideo(String videoPath) async {
    final compressedVideo = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
      videoPath,
      quality: VideoQuality.MediumQuality,
    );

    return compressedVideo!.file;
  }

  _getThumbnail(String videoPath) async {
    final thumbnail = await VideoCompress.getFileThumbnail(videoPath);
    return thumbnail;
  }
```

Comment: Got a temporary solution from this link https://github.com/jonataslaw/VideoCompress/issues/207

Answer (score 2):

if you are facing the build failed error while using video_compress, then you can solve this problem by using the below maven link in  build.gradle:

```
   maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
```

the overal gradle look like this:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
```

} }

it worked for me and it should worked for you too.
Upvote if this tricks works.

Answer (score -1):

Use [video_compress_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/video_compress_plus) instead and make sure to set the `minSdkVersion` to `21` in the app level `build.gradle` on this path: `.\android\app\build.gradle`